# Function missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, typeerror, positional-argument

I'm getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mali03/Desktop/Python/Practice/p2.py", line 18, in <module>
    first.subtraction(1, 2)
TypeError: subtraction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Here is my calculator class

```
class calculator:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def addition(self, x, y):
        return self.x + self.y

    def subtraction(self, x, y):
        if self.x > self.y:
            return self.y - self.x
        else:
            return self.x - self.y
```

I then call subtraction with the following:

```
first = calculator
first.subtraction(1, 2)
```

Comment: Replace `first = calculator` with `first = calculator()`

Comment: You don't need the `x, y` on either of `addition` or `subtraction`. You don't use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like stated previously, you don't have to include parameters in your **addition** or **subtraction** functions if you already gather that information in the **__init__** function.

Like so:

```
class calculator:

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def addition(self):
    return self.x + self.y

def subtraction(self):
    if self.x > self.y:
        return self.y - self.x
    else:
        return self.x - self.y


first = calculator
print(first(5,10).addition())
```

Alternatively, if you *do* want to have **x** and **y** parameters in your **addition** and **subtraction** functions, you can adjust your code like so:

```
class calculator:

def addition(self, x, y):
    return x + y

def subtraction(self, x, y):
    if x > y:
        return y - x
    else:
        return x - y

first = calculator
print(first().addition(5, 10))
```

Where parameters of individual functions are used instead to the parameters given to the class object.

Either ways work, it depends on how you want to use the class.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could do:

```
class calculator():

    def addition(self, x, y):
        return x + y

    def subtraction(self, x, y):
        if x > y:
            return y - x
        else:
            return x - y

first = calculator()
print(first.subtraction(1, 2))
```

Also not entirely sure if x > y: was your intention or if you really wanted if x < y:

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify `x` and `y` in `subtraction` or `addition`:

```
class calculator:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def addition(self):
        return self.x + self.y

    def subtraction(self):
        if self.x > self.y:
            return self.y - self.x
        else:
            return self.x - self.y
```

`self` will cover retrieving `x` and `y` for you, since you are referencing those instance variables. Otherwise, you will need to specify them on call:

```
# Yields 2-1 rather than 4-3
result = calculator(1,2).subtraction(3,4)
```

You do, however, need to specify them when instantiating your class

```
myinst = calculator(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`first = calculator` makes `first` refer to the class. But `first = calculator(1, 2)` makes `first` an object of the class `calculator`. This initializes `self` for all other functions called on `first`. This also sets the values for `self.x` and `self.y` because `__init__` is called as soon as object is created. Hence, when `first = calculator(x, y)` is used, `self` has a value along with `self.x` and `self.y`, and when parentheses are not used, they do not have a value. That gives a missing argument error.

Next, as others have already referred, once `__init__` is called, x and y are initialized for the object. And so, you don't need them while declaring other functions. `self.x` and `self.y` can directly be used there which will now refer to 1 and 2 respectively in this case.

Hope it helps.